# React - Get User Login Credentials and Validate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React project which has a Login Form. I did separate the code into small components so that I can reuse it later. However, I don't know how to get the user credentials (username, and password) and validate it. Is there any method to validate the user credential when the user clicks on the "Sign In" button? Thank you for your help

Login.js

```
import "../css/LoginMain.css";
import LoginButtons from "./LoginButtons";
import LoginInput from "./LoginInput";

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="limiter">
        <div className="container-login100">
          <div className="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33">
            <form
              className="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w"
              action="login.php"
              method="post"
            >
              <span className="login100-form-title p-b-53"> Sign in now</span>
              <LoginInput />
              <a href="forget.html" className="forgot-password">
                Forgot Password?
              </a>
              <LoginButtons />
              <div className="row" />
              <div className="text-black mb-3">or login with</div>
              <div className="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

LoginButtons.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../css/Login.css";
import "../css/LoginMain.css";

class LoginButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17 m-b-20">
        <button type="submit" id="signIn" className="login100-form-btn m-b-10">
          <span>Sign In</span>
        </button>
        <button
          onclick="location.href='../register.html'"
          className="login100-form-btn m-b-10"
        >
          Sign up
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginButtons;
```

LoginInput.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../css/Login.css";
import "../css/LoginMain.css";

class LoginInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input">
          <input
            className="input100"
            type="email"
            id="inputEmail"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            name="email"
            onkeyup="send()"
            required
          />
          <span>
            <i className="focus-input100" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input">
          <input
            className="input100"
            type="password"
            id="inputPassword"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            required
          />
          <span>
            <i className="focus-input100" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading up on how data and control flow works in a React app.
https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

What you have right now is pure UI.
Here updates to the Components needed to do hook up a data model to the UI.

**LoginInput.js**
Add a change handler `onChange` to pass email and password to the parent component. Using props. See [React Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

```
class LoginInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input">
          <input
            className="input100"
            type="email"
            id="inputEmail"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            name="email"
            name="email"
            onkeyup="send()"
            onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange('email', e.target.value)}
            required
          />
          <span>
            <i className="focus-input100" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input">
          <input
            className="input100"
            type="password"
            id="inputPassword"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange('password', e.target.value)}
            name="password"
            required
          />
          <span>
            <i className="focus-input100" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginButtons.js**

New event handler prop `onSignUp`.
Add click handler in the sign-up button. Use this to tell the parent component when user clicks on this sign-up button.

```
class LoginButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17 m-b-20">
        <button type="submit" id="signIn" className="login100-form-btn m-b-10">
          <span>Sign In</span>
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={this.props.onSignUp}
          className="login100-form-btn m-b-10"
        >
          Sign up
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Login.js**

1. Create a state in `Login.js` component. Here we will store the email and password values entered by the user.
2. Capture email and password values from `LoginInput` component using its `onChange` callback.
3. Capture the sign up button click from `LoginButtons` using the `onSignUp` props we added to `LoginButtons` component earlier.  Here you can execute your validation login

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: null,
      password: null
    }
  }
  
  handleLoginFormChange = (fieldName, value) => {
    switch(fieldName) {
      case 'email':
        this.setState({
          email: value
        })
        break;
      case 'password':
        this.setState({
          pasword: value
        })
        break;
    }
  }
  
  handleSignUpClick = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    // execute validation
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="limiter">
        <div className="container-login100">
          <div className="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33">
            <form
              className="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w"
              action="login.php"
              method="post"
            >
              <span className="login100-form-title p-b-53"> Sign in now</span>
              <LoginInput onChange={handleLoginFormChange} />
              <a href="forget.html" className="forgot-password">
                Forgot Password?
              </a>
              <LoginButtons onSignUp={handleSignUpClick} />
              <div className="row" />
              <div className="text-black mb-3">or login with</div>
              <div className="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```